# move_base_node callbacks

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was going through the code for the move_base_node:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_base_node");
  tf::TransformListener tf(ros::Duration(10));
  move_base::MoveBase move_base( tf );
  ros::spin();
  return(0);
}
```

So I'm wondering, what callbacks does the `ros::spin()` at the end execute? The constructor for the MoveBase object has a subscriber, a couple of services, an action server and some other stuff.

And in general, I guess my question is - what callbacks does the ros::spin wait for?

Source: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196910/move_base_node-callbacks/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::spin() blocks until the node is killed with a signal (ctrl-C, segfault, etc) or through `rosnode kill`.

While ros::spin() is running, it services all of the callbacks for all topics, services, etc that are not explicitly handled by a separate spinner.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-06**:
And how would it be handled by a separate spinner?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-06**:
See: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning